# $b_n$ Fourier series $f(x)=x^3$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm having trouble to solve the $b_n$ coefficient of Fourier series of $x^3$ function on the $-\pi<x<\pi$.
The result is almost right, but the powers of $n$ are one less degree I mean

The result is with $(-1)^n[12/n^2]$ (should be $/n^3$) less $2\pi^2$ (should be $/n$).
There must be something I'm doing wrong but I simply can't find my error... Can you please help me out on this?

Thanks
Ams

Comment: "..on the -pi..."?

Comment: There are directions in the FAQ section to write properly mathematics in this wite with LaTeX. Use that, please.

Comment: And after you learn how to write mathematics here (it takes about 5-6 minutes TOPS), describe to us what is it you did that "must be wrong".

Comment: See this. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360705/calculating-the-fourier-series-of-x3/362374#362374

Comment: Thanks but I need to show the results like I did in the other exercises. But there is something wrong on my calculus ...

Comment: This is the result I'm searching for:(-1)^{n}*(12/n^3-2*pi^2/n) I must be doing some calculus wrong but I don't know what!!!!

Comment: You mean $b_n={\frac {2( \left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}+6\, \left( -1
 \right) ^{n})}{{n}^{3}}}.$

Comment: You need to post your work in order for people to spot your mistake.

Comment: No. What I mean the result I need is (((-'1)^n)*((12/(n^3))-((2*pi^2)/n))) and what I have is ((-'1)^n)*((12/(n^2))-(2pi^2))

Comment: I can't post my calculus yeti because e can't post pictures yet. As soon as I can i post my calculus :)

Comment: This is my calculation for bn... Can you please see what is wrong???

http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2169-123.html

Comment: The answer for $b_n$ in my above comment is correct. I am sure of it.

Comment: Just got the right answer!!!! Can close this topic!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take your time to do the calculations. Here is the Fourier series

$$ x^3 = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{ \left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}+6\, \left( -1
 \right)^{n}}{{n}^{3}}} \sin{nx}. $$

Comment: This is the right result for the x3 function on the Fourier series ?

Comment: @Amccds: Yes, it is.

Comment: What am I do doing wrong???

Comment: Can someone please check my image I posted to see my resolution of the integer to help me see what I did wrong??? Please???? Thanks

Comment: Just got the right answer!!!! Can close this topic!!!

Comment: @Amccds: good. It is a matter of calculations. I recommand you not to rush when you do any calculations. Just go step by step.